Powershell script to set only a specific setting in Local Group Policy to 'Not Configured'
Powershell newbie here. I'm trying to automate a scenario where any particular setting in Local Group Policy can be set to 'Not Configured'. For example, I'm trying to set below setting to 'Not Configured'. Now by default this is already set to Not Configured so I would manually enable it first and try to run the Powershell script to reset it back to Not Configured.
E.g:
Path: Administrative Templates > Windows Components > Windows Updates
Setting name: Specify intranet Micrsoft update service location
Below is the script I'm currently testing but it doesn't quite reset it, the setting seems to remain unchanged in gpedit.msc. Based on my research, there were suggestions to use LGPO tool and I have tried that too but result is the same. Even after restarting the machine, the setting remains the same.
# Path to LGPO.exe (ensure you've downloaded and placed this in a proper location)
$lgpoPath = "C:\LGPO\LGPO_30\LGPO.exe"  # Replace with the actual path to LGPO.exe

# Define the registry path for Windows Update Group Policy
$regPathWU = "HKLM:\Software\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\WindowsUpdate"
$regValue1 = "WUServer"
$regValue2 = "WUStatusServer"

# Step 1: Remove only the relevant registry entries for the Windows Update service
If (Test-Path $regPathWU) {
    # Remove the WUServer and WUStatusServer registry values (only these values)
    Remove-ItemProperty -Path $regPathWU -Name $regValue1 -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
    Remove-ItemProperty -Path $regPathWU -Name $regValue2 -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
    Write-Host "'Specify intranet Microsoft update service location' registry values have been removed."
} else {
    Write-Host "Registry path for the policy not found, no action needed."
}

# Step 2: Use LGPO to clear the policy in the Registry.pol file
# Target the specific policy path for 'Specify intranet Microsoft update service location'
& "$lgpoPath" /t machine /clear /p "Administrative Templates\Windows Components\Windows Update\Specify intranet Microsoft update service location"

# Step 3: Force Group Policy update to apply the change
gpupdate /force

Write-Host "The policy 'Specify intranet Microsoft update service location' has been reset to 'Not Configured'."

